# SQL Server Express 2012 Foreign Keys won't populate into tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, null, foreign-keys

I'm about at my wits end here so any help would be appreciated. Here are the three queries I am running:

```
CREATE TABLE Contact
(ContactID  VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
ContactCompanyName  VARCHAR(80),
ContactFirstName    VARCHAR(30),
ContactLastName VARCHAR(30),
EmployeeID  VARCHAR(15),
CONSTRAINT Contact_PK PRIMARY KEY (ContactID));

GO

CREATE TABLE CompanyRepresentative
(EmployeeID VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
RepFirstName    VARCHAR(30),
RepLastName VARCHAR(30),
CONSTRAINT CompanyRepresentative_PK PRIMARY KEY (EmployeeID));

GO
```

Followed by:

```
ALTER TABLE Contact
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_EmployeeID1
FOREIGN KEY(EmployeeID)REFERENCES CompanyRepresentative(EmployeeID);

GO
```

And finally:

```
INSERT dbo.Contact (ContactID, ContactCompanyName, ContactFirstName,    

ContactLastName)
VALUES
('PC7432', 'Krueger Bakeries', 'Brian', 'Jones'),
('PC5317', 'Advanced Data Storage', 'Mark', 'Pulley'),
('PC2931', 'M&D Graphics and Design', 'Mike', 'Dorris'),
('PC1753', 'Apex Digital Solutions', 'Janice', 'Becker'),
('PC8527', 'Infensus Consultants', 'Narbeth', 'Pokrehl');

GO

INSERT dbo.CompanyRepresentative (EmployeeID, RepFirstName, RepLastName)
VALUES
('TBOC53297', 'Mike', 'Hartman'),
('TBOC32781', 'Lynn', 'Kynes'),
('TBOC12783', 'Jason', 'McCann'),
('TBOC43971', 'Susan', 'Mueller'),
('TBOC29753', 'Greg', 'Krebs');

GO
```

When I run

```
select * from Contact
```

The EmployeeID field does not display the value for foreign key EmployeeID from the table dbo.CompanyRepresentative instead it shows "NULL". What am I missing?

Comment: How it will automatically inserts employee id? You have to insert it through your query.

Comment: It will be `NULL` because you're not insert the value for that column. The foreign key in `EmployeeID` will not automatically doing insert the data.

Comment: Adding a foreign key doesn't make it magically populate. The foreign key is a constraint that ensures when *you* insert data in that column, the value is present in the referenced table. In the sample data in your question, which company representative row belongs to which employee? Why?

Answer (score 0):

You have to insert `EmployeeID` like this. Otherwise by default **SQL Server** inserts `NULL` into that field.

```
INSERT dbo.Contact (ContactID, ContactCompanyName, ContactFirstName, ContactLastName, EmployeeID)
VALUES
('PC7432', 'Krueger Bakeries', 'Brian', 'Jones', 'TBOC53297'),
('PC5317', 'Advanced Data Storage', 'Mark', 'Pulley','TBOC32781'),
('PC2931', 'M&D Graphics and Design', 'Mike', 'Dorris','TBOC12783'),
('PC1753', 'Apex Digital Solutions', 'Janice', 'Becker','TBOC43971'),
('PC8527', 'Infensus Consultants', 'Narbeth', 'Pokrehl','TBOC29753');

GO
```

Comment: Thanks! That's what I thought I needed to do, but it wasn't working in a larger database I'm working on because of the FK_constraints. It will take me longer but UPDATE will save the day.